# How do I automatically change the assignee of a bug back to the reporter when a bug is marked RESOLVED?

Tags: bugzilla

We have a workflow where all incoming bugs are marked ASSIGNED to their product's default assignee, then they stay in ASSIGNED until RESOLVED by the assignee.

At that point, they go either from RESOLVED back to ASSIGNED (e.g. not done yet) or to CLOSED once they reporter is satisfied.

How do we automatically change the assignee of the bug to the reporter when the first assignee marks it RESOLVED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is pretty easy with Bugzilla hooks.  Where the extension code needs to go will depend on what version you are using, because this is a capability that's rapidly developing.

In Bugzilla 3.6.1, the current version, if you wanted to call your extension `Local`, you would create a file `extensions/Local/Extension.pm`.

http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.6/en/html/api/Bugzilla/Extension.html is the overview of the whole extension system.

The hook you want to use for this is `bug_end_of_update`, which is called in `Bugzilla/Bug.pm` after the object is changed but before it is written to the database.

For what you're doing, you should probably check `changes` to see whether `bug_status` has changed.  If so, update `bug` to set the owner to the reporter, and add that change to `changes`.

The main developers of Bugzilla can usually be found on #mozwebtools on irc.mozilla.org, drop in and chat them up about the particulars if my answer isn't enough to get you rolling.

Answer (score 0):

This will work: (CustomExtension.pm)

```
package Bugzilla::Extension::CustomExtension;
use strict;
use base qw(Bugzilla::Extension);

our $VERSION = '1.0';
use constant NAME => 'CustomExtension';

sub object_end_of_set_all {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;

    my $object = $args->{'object'};

    if ($object->isa('Bugzilla::Bug')) {
        if ($object->{'bug_status'} eq 'RESOLVED') {            # Bug has been RESOLVED
            $object->{'assigned_to'} = $object->{'reporter_id'};    # re-assign to Reporter
        }
    }
}

__PACKAGE__->NAME;
```